# Tensorflow, delete element from matrixs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want know how to delete an element from a matrix in a tensor.

```
a = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[0, 0, 0, 0],[2, 2, 2, 2],[1, 1, 1, 1]])

b = tf....(a)
#desired output of b, if I want to remove the second element in dim 1 of "a"
[[0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1]]
#desired output of b, if I want to remove the last element in dim 1 of "a"
[[0, 0, 0, 0],[2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice and then Stack

```
a = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[0, 0, 0, 0],[2, 2, 2, 2],[1, 1, 1, 1]])
b = tf.stack([a[0], a[2]]) #[[0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1]]
c = tf.stack([a[0], a[1]]) #[[0, 0, 0, 0],[2, 2, 2, 2]]
```